Re-use a SSH Key Generated on an Ubuntu Machine on a Windows Machine
I once generated a SSH key on Ubuntu and have been using that key in different apps and services such as Visual Studio Code and DigitalOcean.
Right now, I don't have access to that Ubuntu machine and all I have is the content of
~/.ssh/id_rsa file on that Ubuntu machine and it looks like below:
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- A Bunch Of Random Characters -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

I'm currently on a Windows machine using JetBrains' WebStorm, and I need to develop a project on a remote Linux server by the help of SSH.
So I copied over the above contents to a file in my home directory and instructed WebStorm to use this file as the private key, but so far, WebStorm is unable to use this file and responds a message that says "Invalid Credentials".
See the screen shot of Webstorm when it's throwing the error
The Linux server is correctly set up and includes my public key and is indeed accessible globally.
How can I re-use my SSH key on this new Windows machine to develop a project on a remote Linux server through SSH using JetBrains' WebStorm ?

It would be a guess, but it's possible that your private key is having a problem with line endings. ---- BEGIN PRIVATE KEY ----- should be on a line by itself, as should ----- END PRIVATE KEY -----.  As a first try, edit the key file so that those are on separate lines; DO NOT touch the random-looking characters. And do keep a copy of the original file you brought over from the Ubuntu machine.

I carried out your suggestion, but no luck. I even used a tool called dos2unix to change the line endings from Windows to Unix, still no luck. I have used the public key of this key in many places and it would be a very time-consuming task to update all those places with a new public key.

@tsc_chazz So, turned out the ssh directory on the Linux server was named ssh instead of  .ssh. A whole day was wasted. Thanks for trying to help.

I have a key generated on Windows machine and want to use in Ubuntu machine now, is it possible?
When I try to SSH I get this error:
"sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed for ED25519 "/home//.ssh/id_ed25519" from agent: agent refused operation"

Ok, in my case it was permission issue because I manually copied private key from windows to ubuntu's .ssh dir.
So running chmod 700 ~/.ssh and chmod 600 ~/.ssh/* solved it!
Thanks to this SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50773234/11781331
